# How can I merge a Gmail account and OpenID account with Superuser?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid, gmail

I have recently created an account with Super User with a Gmail account
Now that I'm trying to login in only find the OpenID login
and when i login with my OpenID it seems Super User doesn't recognize it with my Gmail account
The result is I have 2 accounts now an old one(Gmail) with reputation and a new one without (OpenID)
When I First Signup I did it with Windows 7 now I'm working with Ubuntu 10.10

So my question is:
**How can i merge my previously superuser Gmail account and my OpenID account with Super User?**

Comment: has been asked before as well

Answer (score 4):

After the account creation process I don't think you can merge your accounts. Gmail accounts themselves can be [**used as an OpenID account directly**](http://technofriends.in/2008/11/10/what-is-openid-and-how-to-use-your-gmail-account-as-openid/). If you want your accounts merged, I would contact the dev team at team@superuser.com.

Comment: Thank you +1 John T for your quick answer.At one point, I couldn't figure out that i could actually login with my gmail account directly as there was no alternatives at the login page. I've contact the dev team hope they can find a practical solution.